# SQL error 206 in Interbase with Delphi with alias

Tags: sql, select, alias

I'm using this SQL:

```
SELECT sys_tbldef_desc as tbldef_desc
FROM sys_tbldef
WHERE UPPER(tbldef_desc) = UPPER('a tbldef desc')
```

And I get this error:

```
Error at line 1 - Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
TBLDEF_DESC
```

Does anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys_tbldef
where UPPER(case when sys_tbldef_trnslt_desc is null
then sys_tbldef_desc else sys_tbldef_trnslt_desc end) = UPPER('a table desc')
```

Answer (score 5):

you can't use `ALIAS` on `WHERE` clause. The SQL Order of operation is as follow

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause       (*the alias takes place here*)
- ORDER BY clause

The `WHERE` clause is executed first before the `SELECT` clause. You should use the column name instead. eg:

```
SELECT sys_tbldef_desc as tbldef_desc
FROM sys_tbldef
WHERE UPPER(sys_tbldef_desc) = UPPER('a tbldef desc')
```

If you really want to use `ALIAS`, a subquery is required, eg:

```
SELECT tbldef_desc
FROM
(
    SELECT sys_tbldef_desc as tbldef_desc
    FROM sys_tbldef
) a
WHERE UPPER(tbldef_desc) = UPPER('a tbldef desc')
```

But I prefer the first one.

Comment: post the error please. and the query you are executing so well' know.

Comment: **CORRECTED** in postgresql, I **can** use alias within *where*

Comment: Error at line 1
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 4, char 3
SELECT
SQL - SELECT tbldef_omschr
FROM
(
    SELECT sys_tbldef_omschr as tbldef_omschr
    FROM sys_tbldef
)
WHERE UPPER(tbldef_omschr) = 'MATERIEELSOORTEN'

Comment: @Teysz since you have used a subquery, you need to add an `ALIAS` on it, eg `( SELECT sys_tbldef_omschr as tbldef_omschr FROM sys_tbldef ) s` see the example.

Comment: see the example i have supplied `a` after the subquery.

Comment: @Teysz no, it should work, see here [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/404ac/1)

Comment: kindly check the query, or provide me a screenshot about the query you are executing and the error thrown. `:D`

Comment: @JW maybe that is only possible in MySQL, but it does not work in Interbase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22035/discussion-between-teysz-and-jw)

Answer (score 2):

You can not use alias names in WHERE clause and your query should be,

```
SELECT sys_tbldef_desc as tbldef_desc
FROM sys_tbldef
WHERE UPPER(sys_tbldef_desc) = UPPER('a tbldef desc')
```